# execute a batch file from a program

Tags: c++, c, windows, batch-file

i would like to execute a batch file from a program (exe file). i usually create the batch file while program (exe file) execution. and will the execl("START","",NULL);

the function is calling the batch file, but unfortunately new command window is showing up as the execl function is process START and parses as “cmd.exe /k "
.

can you please share the easiest way to call the function which executes the batch file in background, if possible please share the code snippet.

Comment: i have tried this and its works like a charm.

CreateProcess( <loc of batch file>, <loc of batch file>, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `start` but `cmd /c`.

**ETA:** As Chris Jester-Young notes in a comment, this will then look like

```
execlp("cmd", "/c", batchfile, static_cast<char*>(0))
```

in your code.

**ETA 2:** It appears that you don't even need `cmd` there. Just the batch file as command should suffice. Since `start` worked and `start` is a built-in command of `cmd.exe` there *has to be* an instance of `cmd` running for your original invocation to work. So just execute the batch file as if it were the program, this should suffice.

Comment: Which, here, translates to `execlp("cmd", "/c", batchfile, static_cast<char*>(0))`.

Comment: @Chris, thanks. My experience with C++ and C is quite limited. The underlying problem was pretty obvious, though.

Comment: execlp() API says, first argument should be path of the file to execute , does this interpret cmd to cmd.exe ?

Comment: @Venkat: Try it out. I honestly have no idea. You can put cmd.exe in there too if you like.

Comment: @Johannes: No worries. If you're curious, read http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html for more info on the various `exec*` functions. The `static_cast<char*>(0)` is the C++ way of expressing `(char *) 0` which is listed in their documentation.

Comment: @Venkat: You may have to use `cmd.exe`, yes. I haven't done enough Windows programming to tell you one way or the other. (Cygwin will automatically do `.exe` resolution for you, but can't speak about other Windows programming environments.)

Comment: @Venkat: On second thought, you only need the batch file directly; see the second edit.

Comment: @Johannes: Huh, how interesting (that `exec*` can execute shell builtins, at least for the OP's environment). I certainly do not expect the same to work in Unix; there, using `sh -c ...` is required. :-P

Comment: @Chris: That was inferred from the OP's original usage. But I faintly remember some docs by MS that said so. But batch files can be run like normal programs in any case, afaik; but especially so if there is a shell already executing that ;-)

Comment: @johannes and @chris , the only function call working is system() and not the execl and execlp are not at all executing... and also i would like to execute the batch file in background.... user should not be prompted with new command screen nor any popup should appear.